# How can I create semi dynamic byte array

Tags: c#

How can generate a byte dynamically in c# code?

Format as below :

First byte is standard 88, second byte is the number of remaining byte, and the last one is the remaining bytes.

Example:

1 byte:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x88, 0x01, 0};
```

2 bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x88, 0x02, 0, 0};
```

5 bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x88, 0x05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what problem you have and question missing sample code that you've tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just this:

```
    static byte[] Get(byte num)
    {
        byte[] a = new byte[num + 2];
        a[0] = 0x88;
        a[1] = num;
        return a;
    }
```

All the other bytes are initialized by default with 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data bytes in an array, you can create an array dynamically like this:

```
// data bytes
byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };

byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Length + 2];
buffer[0] = 0x88;
buffer[1] = (byte)data.Length;
data.CopyTo(buffer, 2);
```

If you create the data bytes in some other way, the first part of the code is the same, then just put the data in the rest of the array in the same way as the first two bytes. For example five zero bytes:

```
int len = 5;

byte[] buffer = new byte[len + 2];
buffer[0] = 0x88;
buffer[1] = (byte)len;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  buffer[i + 2] = 0;
}
```

Comment: You won't actually need that loop. They initialize to 0 already. Also, when you get to i = len - 2, your code will throw an error.

Comment: @JoshVarty: You are missing the point, the code is for showing how to put values in the array. Why would there be an error when i = len - 2?

Comment: My mistake, I realize now you defined `len` not as the length of the array, but as its own variable. There are no errors.